# Warning when submitting my app with Google Maps SDK for iOS Ver.1.9.0

Tags: ios, xcode, google-maps-sdk-ios

I recently replaced Google Maps SDK for iOS Ver.1.8.1 by the latest one, Ver.1.9.0, 
and submitted to iTunes Connect trough Xcode 6.1, but I received the following error:

---

The archive passed validation with several warnings:

iTunes Store operation failed.
The app references non-public selectors in Payload/XXXXXX.app/XXXXXX: userEmail

---

(XXXXXX: my app name)

Have anybody seen and avoid the same error??
I don't know if I can ignore this issue and my app can pass the Apple's review.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It seems to be a known issue.

There is a workaround listed here https://code.google.com/p/gmaps-api-issues/issues/detail?id=7310

> One work around is to include GTM-OAuth -
>   https://code.google.com/p/gtm-oauth/ - in your project. Another
>   possible work around is to add the following code to your project:

```
@interface UserEmailStubWorkaround
@property(nonatomic, readonly) NSString *userEmail;
@end
@implementation UserEmailStubWorkaround
@end
```

Comment: Thx. i could confirm the warning disappeared by adding your code.

Answer (score 1):

This issue was resolved on Ver.1.9.1. Thx all.

Answer (score 0):

I faced the same issue a short while ago, But i just replaced Google Maps SDK for iOS Ver.1.9.0 with the latest one i-e Ver.1.9.1. Everything was fine and validation was done successfully. So, try by replacing Google Maps SDK for iOS with latest version.